# jq function to convert a stream of strings into a single array

Tags: jq

I am trying to get an array of all possible paths in a JSON Document.

Given the document:

```
{
  "a": "bar",
  "b": [
   {"c": 3}, {"d": 6},
   {"c": 7}, {"d": 5}
  ]
}
```

I'd like the output to be:
["","a","b","b/0","b/0/c","b/1","b/1/d","b/2","b/2/c","b/3","b/3/d"]

I got pretty close, here is a [snippet](https://jqplay.org/s/b7q_1tfuFv) on the JQ Playground.

Comment: Just wrap the expression in square brackets. Since your `tostring` is unnecessary you end up with `[path(..)|[.[]]|join("/")]`

Comment: @peak Why the fuzz with `.. | [.[]] | ..` and not just `[path(..) | join("/")]`?

Comment: @pmf - I was just answering the question in the "title".  The implied complement of "you end up with" was "Starting with your approach".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try

```sh
jq '["", (paths | join("/"))]'
```

[Demo](https://jqplay.org/s/1rhPnJJ3yx)